# GoogleMap (Javascript) : How to highlight a land area (region)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to highlight a Land Area (Region) on GoogleMap by using Javascript Library. But there are different (so called) components / tools **given in GoogleMap** for this purpose. Like:

- Polygons
- Overlays
- KML Layers
- Data Layers

[This example](http://www.ourenseverde.es/espazos/) is what I found as a nice example to refer. (I need to highlight (color) the land areas (regions) like that. Are these "Polygons"? Or "Overlays"? etc?)

Which **component is supposed to use** to highlight a region on Map please?

(or)

How do i color (highlight) the land area in GoogleMap?

Comment: I can't tell exactly from your example, but they look like overlays. See googles own example of overlays and decide if you can work with them the way you want to: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow

Comment: A simple way would be Polygons. Guess this component would provide you everything you need

Answer (score 0):

Google maps user interface is implemented as a canvas, so I believe you can use any canvas drawing library.

Yo can for example use Paper.js or raphael.js

Comment: Thanks. But i think you misunderstood my question. :) I just wanna know, in GoogleMaps, what "tool", "component" should i use to highlight a land area?